# Swift TableView AddressBook Array Error

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, addressbook

I have tableview and inside there i have address book items (firstName, lastName, phone) So i have cell which shows only the last property from my device multiplied on `numberOfRowsInSection` but after that i have `println()` and it gives me the whole list of contact names. I could not understand why is this all happening please help me. To Recap: In Xcode I Have Whole List Of Contacts But On The Device i Have Only The Last One And 5 times.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(textCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
        let row = indexPath.row

            let allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(AddressBookForVC).takeRetainedValue() as NSArray
            for person: ABRecordRef in allPeople{

                let firstName = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty)?.takeRetainedValue() as! String? ?? ""
                let lastName  = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty)?.takeRetainedValue() as! String? ?? ""
                let phones: ABMultiValueRef = ABRecordCopyValue(person,kABPersonPhoneProperty).takeRetainedValue()

                let countOfPhones = ABMultiValueGetCount(phones)

                for index in 0..<countOfPhones{
                    let phone = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, index).takeRetainedValue() as! String

                    //  println("\(firstName) \(lastName) \(phone)")

                    cell.textLabel?.text = firstName
                    println(firstName)

                }
            }

     //   cell.textLabel?.text = swiftBlogs[row]

        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called once for every row in the table. And each time you're calling `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, you're extracting and iterating though the array of all contacts each time.

The code for copying/looping all of the contacts doesn't make sense inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Usually you'd extract all of that information earlier (e.g. in `viewDidLoad`), and populate an array once. Then `cellForRowAtIndexPath` would simply look up data in that array, not going back to the address book and re-extracting all of the contacts every time.